# Angularjs directive show toaster of different type on basis of a condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to write a angular directive, which will show the angular toaster for notification. I am not doing on click of any button. I want this to show this toaster based on some condition. My directive sample is as shown below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("MyModule")
        .directive('toasterContainer', function () {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope: {
                    messageType:'='
                }
            };
        })
})();

<toaster-container message-type='error'></toaster-container>
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve this?Basically i dont know how to create condition based template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster that is a great package for toaster.

Based on it; after adding your HTML code ; you need to call your toaster into js as is :

```
toaster.pop('info', "title", "text");
```

if you need to add control; just add some if / else conditions :

```
if(test === true) 
   toaster.pop('info', "title", "text");
else 
   toaster.pop('warn', "title", "text");
```

Comment: thank you. I am not using that angularjs-toaster. i am trying with simple one. which will display the angular material toaster.